# Dynamic Sized Image in Google Sheets For Printing Based On Cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts, google-drawings

I've made a [calculator](https://www.olympicpistol.com/target-calculator/) with Google Sheets to make it easier for Olympic shooters to train at home. The data that it produces is very helpful, but I would like to make it easier for the users to print their targets by being able to just print an image in the sheet (if possible just by clicking a link).

The image I'm looking for is just a black circle, very simple. I want this circle to print at the exact size given by the calculator.

I've not been able to do it with the `image()` formula, nor with Google Drawing [(example)](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1CQbKs5a-K808hjKphFgzvxFBjiuEZKpL3T5R3Dx_pM0/edit?usp=sharing).